# Is there an effective way for me to see all recently created answers regardless of edits?

Tags: discussion, answers

I can see all questions sorted by posting time ( http://$SITE/questions )

I can see all questions sorted by last modification to any content - new Q, new A, but ***also modifications form edits to Q or A*** (http://$SITE/ "Active" tab)

Can I easily see a list of all new answers, sorted by answer posing time, NOT by create-or-edit time?

- This needs to be realtime, so answers using SE Data Explorer aren't acceptable, sorry
- I don't care if questions are included in the feed of answer, or not - as long as edits to questions aren't included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for `is:a` and sort by "Newest" (which sorts by creation date, not last activity).

Done.

> [image]

You can use the `created:` option to further narrow the search by creation date if you want to, but without it will just return everything—which sounds like what you want.

The URL for the search would be:

```
http://$SITE/search?tab=newest&q=is:a
```

Comment: Actually, the typical use would be "what new answers were posted since yesterday", so "created:" is an extremely useful addition to your answer. thanks!